# reading file and storing values in an array

Tags: arrays, csv

Here am reading my csv file,and then am trying to append those generated values to an array or list ,ihave used append() ,but when am printing the array it is shoeing as 'None'

my csv file Book1.csv is having these values

```
A
B
C


list = [0]
open_file = open("C:/user/01/Desktop/Book1.csv",'rb')
file = csv.reader(open_file)
for value in file:
     print value
final1 = list.append(value)
print "array"
print final1
```

Then it is printing final1 as 'None'
I want to show final1 as  [A,B,C]..please help........
Thanks in advance..............

Comment: I don't recognize the language you're using, but it looks like you're not setting the value of final1 in the for loop.  Are there brackets or something to include the `final1 =` in the for loop?

Comment: Can you please tel the programming language you are using.

Comment: i got it:),i made a mistake,here i am assigning list.append to final1,so  i have printed list directly without using final1..thanks:)

Comment: python  programming language @Afroz Alam

Comment: ok so you can self answer and close this question. Thanks